# Use : instead of comma with biblatex chicago author-date

Tags: formatting, citing, biblatex-chicago

The four-hour rule has kicked in: I haven't found an answer to this in 4 hrs., so I'm asking here.

I'm using Biblatex-Chicago Author-Date with Biber. A typical in-text citation looks like "(Jones, 2016, 12)" for an item written by Jones, published in 2016, and referencing page 12. But I want it to look like "(Jones 2016: 12)."

I've managed to get rid of the first comma, the one between "Jones" and "2016," by inserting "\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}" in my preamble. But I've looked and looked and can't find a field like nameyeardelim that delimits the author-year information from the page(s) information.

If you can not only suggest how to accomplish this but also direct me to a place where this stuff is documented, I'd be most appreciative.

## Note

The Biblatex documentation may have this, but part of my frustration is that this particular style of citation, using the comma, might be coming from Biber, Biblatex, or the Chicago package -- not only the software itself but the particular combination of options used to invoke each one. And this really presents a haystack for the needle that's the comma being inserted in the citation.

Comment: Well, lacking a MWE I can't test, but I'd say you are looking for `\postnotedelim`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}`.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Jones2016,
    author = {Jones, John},
    title = {Title},
    date = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\begin{document}

\parencite[12]{Jones2016}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would also be nice to have some idea of how to find this answer in the documentation, esp. if one does not know they're looking for "\postnotedelim." This would be helpful in future treasure hunts.

Comment: Well, the documentation does have a section on "Formatting commands", the 3.11. `\postnotedelim` is included there, and it is quite semantic in this case. But, I admit, the documentation can sometimes be daunting. It is still the basic reference on the matter tough.