# Reformat editor punctuation in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

Working with biblatex-chicago in the memoir class, for works with only an editor, I need "ed." *not* to be preceded by a comma in citations and bibliography. That is, instead of

> Firstname Lastname, ed.

I'd like

> Firstname Lastname ed.

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413458/use-instead-of-comma-with-biblatex-chicago-author-date?rq=1) and the biblatex manual, I tried

```
\renewcommand{\editortypedelim}{\space}
```

but this produced an error (\editortypedelim undefined), and I'm not even sure if that's the right thing to be modifying, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false,sorting=nyt,giveninits=true,useprefix=false,shorthandfull]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@book{lastname98,
editor = {Firstname Lastname},
title = {A Book},
date = {1898},
address = {City},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Have a sentence.\autocite{lastname98}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `editortypedelim` is a relatively recent addition to `biblatex` and it is not at all unlikely that some contributed styles may not have picked it up (some style like `biblatex-chicago` redefine a lot of things and will overwrite or ignore the predefined standard macros using `editortypedelim`). Note that `editortypedelim` is a context-sensitive delimiter (according to the manual) and thus should be redefined with `\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{...}` and ideally not with `\renewcommand{\editortypedelim}{...}` (but the latter will work in simple cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `biblatex-chicago` style uses `\editordelim` (which is not in the manual) instead of `\editortypedelim`. If you redefine this the comma disappears:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes,shorthandibid,backend=biber,addendum=false,sorting=nyt,giveninits=false,useprefix=false,shorthandfull]{biblatex-chicago}
\renewcommand{\editordelim}{\addspace}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@book{lastname98,
editor = {Firstname Lastname},
title = {A Book},
date = {1898},
address = {City},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Have a sentence.\autocite{lastname98}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that your MWE used `giveninits=true` which prints initials for the first name. In the code above this option is false which means the name is printed in full, but the last name is printed before the first name.